# Roo gem: cell background color

Tags: ruby, roo-gem

I'm using the Roo ruby gem to parse an xlsx file.

Is there any way to get the background color of a cell? I've looked all around the code but couldn't find how to do it.

Opening a spreadsheet using roo is very straightforward:

```
spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file_path)
# Get me a sheet
sheet = spreadsheet.sheet("278")
# I happily thought excelx_format would return something that has
# to do with color, but it (sensibly) returns the cell format.
# In this case is GENERAL (no particular format)
puts sheet.excelx_format(6, 6)
```

Comment: Welcome to the community.  Can you share a sample list of code of what you have already tried?

Comment: roo does not have implemented reader for background color

Comment: Damn. You seem to know more about this than I do :) Any suggestions on how to proceed? Any "advanced" parsing feature that I could use with roo, like a method call to return raw cell information that I could parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked around a little more and Roo does not seem to provide any advanced functions for custom inspection.

So I switched gems. I'm using [spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) now.

```
spreadsheet = Spreadsheet.open(file_path)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("278")
row = sheet.row(5)
background_color = row.format(5).pattern_bg_color
```

Comment: Nice, but it can't open XLSX.
RubyXL can read it, but no grayscales.